# Angular Guard - Subscription not Unsubscribing on Page Change When Loading is False

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, guard

I'm facing an issue with Angular Guards and subscriptions. I have an AuthGuard where I want to unsubscribe from a subscription once the loading is false. However, even after implementing the unsubscribe logic, the subscription continues to be called when I change the page.

Here's a snippet of my AuthGuard code:

```
export class AuthGuard  {
  private subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService,
    protected globalMessage: GlobalMessageService
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    console.log(state.url);

    // Check if the route contains "/login" and a "token" parameter
    if (state.url.includes('/login/validation-compte') && next.queryParams['token']) {
      // Call a method to validate the token (replace this with your actual method)
      const isValidToken = this.validateToken(next.queryParams['token']);
      return true;
    }

    return true; // Allow navigation for other routes
  }

  private validateToken(token: string) {
    // Replace this with your actual token validation logic
    // Return true if the token is valid, false otherwise

    this.subscription = this.loginService.validateRegistration(token).subscribe((validateObject: any) => {
      console.log("here", validateObject);

      if (validateObject.loading === false) {
        if (validateObject.error.error.errors[0].type === "TokenInvalidatedError") {
          this.globalMessage.add(
            { key: 'loginForm.activation.TokenInvalidatedError' },
            GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
          );
        } else if (validateObject.error === false) {
          this.globalMessage.add(
            { key: 'loginForm.activation.OK' },
            GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_CONFIRMATION
          );
        }
// Unsubscribe after processing the result
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've tried to unsubscribe within the validateToken method, but the subscription is still active after changing the page. Any insights into why this might be happening and how I can ensure the subscription is unsubscribed when the page changes?

loginService.validateRegistration(...) is a method that triggers an HTTP call. Depending on the returned object, I perform an unsubscription action. After the completion of the HTTP call, I evaluate the response whether it indicates an error or not. Here's an example of the returned object from this method: `{data: undefined, error: false, loading: true}` during loading, and `{data: data, error: false, loading: false}` upon completion.

Comment: To give you an answer we need to see how you configured your routes and navigation between pages. Also I am not sure if you unsubscribed at all because you have a condition `validateObject.loading === false`. Did you count subscribes/unsubscribes? Maybe some subscription leaked. In addition it would be great to know how `loginService.validateRegistration(...)` internally works. If this method simply makes an HTTP call, then unsubscription is not required at all.

Comment: loginService.validateRegistration(...) is a method that triggers an HTTP call. Depending on the returned object, I perform an unsubscription action. After the completion of the HTTP call, I evaluate the response—whether it indicates an error or not.                                                                                                                         
Here's an example of the returned object from this method: `{data: undefined, error: false, loading: true}` during loading, and `{data: data, error: false, loading: false}` upon completion.

Comment: you have to update the question with all the info, not add it as a separate comment. `triggers an HTTP call` - this means that your subscription was completed/unsubscribed automatically https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server